# How to Backup Database on Database Creation Date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a scenario, On every start of the month new database is dynamically created and we have to take backup of newly created database.
Full database backup is not required only backup is required for newly created databases,  so how how can I take backup of these newly created databases?

Comment: use `backup database` command ! And since this is a newly created database, you have to perform a full backup

Comment: "Full database backup is not required only backup is required for newly created databases". Does this mean that you're not backing up all of your databases all of the time? If so, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your databases won't be renamed,you can use below DMV to find out database creation date..

```
select create_Date from sys.databases
```

Psuedo code goes like this..

1.Run above DMV through a SQLServer job each day and check database creation date..

```
if exists(select 1 from sys.databases 
where convert(varchar(10),create_Date,112)=convert(varchar(10),getdate(),112))
begin
//Backup code
End
```

Comment: Database name changed upon creation,Database prefix remain same but its suffix changes as date of creation. i.e EXAMPLE_11608 (1 is silent, 16 year, 08 month), next month when database will create its name will be EXAMPLE_11609 (1 is silent, 16 year, 09 month)

Comment: @Taoqir:if this is one time change ,then its fine.Schedule your job after that changes

Comment: This is not a one time change, it is recursive on every month starts

Comment: @Taoqir:That will be fine

Comment: Please check following link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cc8954e-6590-45d7-8c1f-aa31ba8674aa/how-to-backup-database-on-database-creation-date?forum=sqlkjmanageability

Answer (score 0):

Use an ALERT from the SQL Server Agent.

This will generate a WMI alert every time someone creates a new database:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'New Database Created', 
    @wmi_namespace=N'\\.\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ServerEvents\MSSQLSERVER', 
    @wmi_query=N'Select * from CREATE_DATABASE', 
    @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

You can either plug in the job_id of your backup job or manually configure a response through SQL Server Management Studio.